# UISwitch in tableview row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

In the code below I'm populating my table with some data. The switches are off which they don't have to be. In the storyboard I defined it as On.

Cell:

```
var switchHandler: ((Bool)->Void)?

@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.switchHandler?(sender.isOn)
}
```

View controller:

```
var selectedCells = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell

    cell?.PhonNumberLbl.text = data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.phoneNumber
    cell?.NameLbl.text = data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.name
    cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)!

    cell?.selectedTF.isOn = self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
    cell?.switchHandler = { (switchState) in
        if switchState {
            self.selectedCells.insert(indexPath)
        } else {
            self.selectedCells.remove(indexPath)
        }
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Model:

```
typealias smsModelList = [SmsModel]

struct SmsModel:Codable {
    var unitNo:Int?
    var unitPlaque:String?
    var billText:String?
    var contacts:[ContactsModel?]
}

typealias contactlistmodel = [ContactsModel]

struct ContactsModel:Codable
{
    var id :Int?
    var selected :Bool?
    var phoneNumber : String?
    var name : String?
}
```

Does anybody see somthing wrong which turns off the switch?

Comment: Hi jack. Where in the `UIViewController` is the code found? Your code is somewhat incomplete so it's hard to guess your context. Specifically, I'm not sure where `indexPath` came from. So I'm not sure which method this code exists in, whether it's a delegate method implementation or a custom one. Could you specify please?

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please edit your question to show the code in context; what functions are those lines contained in? You are setting the on state based on some data in your model and your selected set; you should probably only be using one of these

Answer (score 1):

First of all as you force unwrap the cell anyway do it in the `dequeue` line to avoid the unnecessary amount of question marks and use the API to return a non-optional cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell", for: indexPath) as! SmsTableViewCell
```

To fix your issue update the `selected` property of the `ContactsModel` struct directly and forget the extra `selectedCells` array. Further declare – at least – `selected` as non-optional, practically there is no *maybe* state. And declare also all data source arrays (`data` / `contacts`) as non-optional, `cellForRow` is called only if there is an item at the particular indexPath by default.

```
struct ContactsModel : Codable {
   ...
   var selected : Bool
   ...
}

...

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell", for: IndexPath) as! SmsTableViewCell
let contact = data[indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]
cell.PhonNumberLbl.text = contact.phoneNumber
cell.NameLbl.text = contact.name
cell.selectedTF.isOn = contact.selected

cell.switchHandler = { [unowned self] switchState in
    // as the structs are value types you have to specify the full reference to the data source array
    self.data[indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row].selected = switchState
}
```

Consider to use classes rather than structs in this case then you can shorten the closure

```
cell.switchHandler = { switchState in
    contact.selected = switchState
}
```

Comment: hello sir, and I'm sorry that I'm late to check your answer for my question. I've been a bit busy! is there a way instead of doing this, for example, I could add a switch to the navigation controller, to turn all on or off with that one button?

Comment: What do you mean with *instead of doing this*?

Comment: in this method, user turn on or off the switches  row by row

Comment: Of course it's possible, change all `selected` properties and reload the table view.

Comment: could you explain it please

Comment: I did explain. In the IBAction of the the switch in the navigation bar (actually two buttons *select all* / *deselect all* are more appropriate) set the mentioned `selected` properties in the model and reload the table view.

Comment: I have created the IBAction but I don't understand the "set the mentioned selected properties in the model" :|

Comment: You have to implement my suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use both

```
cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)! 
cell?.selectedTF.isOn = self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
```

so `isOn` property of the switch is controlled from 2 sides , so you have to decide which line that should be commnented , plus don't depend on storyboard prototype cell setup as because of cell reusing it' ll be changed , if you want to make them all on by default then change the var `selectedCells` to contain all possible indexPaths and comment the other one

Comment: if I delete cell?.selectedTF.isOn = self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
, it will not create the property for me to be able to call a method from api, so, I have to delete cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)!

Comment: what do you mean by: "change the var selectedCells to contain all possible indexPaths and comment the other one"

Comment: i mean make a for loop and insert all possible indexPaths according to number of sections and rows , so when ask contains inside cellForRowAt it' ll return true for all so all will be on , and comment this line **cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data! [indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)!**

Comment: I get the status with a for loop and I put them in cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)!

Comment: then remove the other Set and manipulate that array **contacts** you commented

Comment: the other one is used because whenever user change the switch, it will Automatically insert or remove that id from array